# jQuery sidebarToggler needs to expand and collapse using a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a .html page where i have used a jQuery script named sidebar toggler. I have several sidebar toggle option in one page. I need to expand all sidebars in one click or collapse all in one click. But, I unable. Please help me to write a function with that script.

I hope you will find a solution for me.

Please update my script at jsFiddle.net

http://jsfiddle.net/aynamohol/PNs7m/9/

Thanks

Comment: If you post the relevant code in your question you are likely to get a  much better response than asking people to download some random .zip file. Try to reproduce your problem on http://jsfiddle.net and link to that too.

Comment: I have updated the links instead of .zip folder.... Do you have time to check little?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your script. You will find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/PNs7m/11/

The updates are:

- Added an ID attribute in the "Expand(Show)/Collapse all divs using this link by one click, thanks" anchor tag.
- Simplified the JavaScript code.

Please note that I have not fully solved the issue as I have no documentation of the library used for the toogle functionality, but I left a way to handle this functionality using the `trigger` function. Hope that it will help you. :)

Comment: If you think that the answer is acceptable, then you should the accept the answer :)